# Angular 7 - Error after upgrading a project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a project that was created in Angular 6. I am trying to upgrade it to version 7. I have gone through many articles and was able to perform the upgrade.  But when I run ng serve command I am getting the following:

ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.3.0 but 3.4.5 was found instead.

If I lower typescript version to something like 3.1.1 then I get tons of TypeScript errors coming from node_modules folder. Any idea what's to do?

Thanks

Comment: Seems kinda weird that angular 6 supported TS 3.4.5 if angular 7 doesn't, but if what you're saying is true then, Lower it to 3.3.0 and replace any libraries that require 3.4.5.

Comment: <replace any libraries that require 3.4.5. How would I find these libraries?

Comment: When you down grade to 3.3.0 You'll see errors during compilation.

Comment: but TBH I would be more suprised if Angular broke backwards compatibility.  Unless you were using an unsupported version from the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using old version of angular compilerTry updating angular compiler to latest and check,

Run `ng update` this will update your package.json and then 
delete node_modules and npm-cache folder and then run `npm install`

Mine latest angular compiler shows this in package.json

```
"@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
```

Comment: I will run ng update and npm install again, but my package says "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15" as well.

Comment: I have "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15" too.

Comment: This command generates the following output: npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@7.2.15 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.1.1 <3.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. There are more messages like this, but it's not enough space in the comment window.

Comment: IN prev. comment the command was npm install "@angular/compiler"

Comment: If I do that then I get many errors that look like this: ERROR in node_modules/ts-enum-util/dist/types/index.d.ts(23,101): error TS2344: Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'. Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. node_modules/ts-enum-util/dist/types/index.d.ts(76,57): error TS2344: Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'. Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: "ts-enum-util": "^2.0.2"

Comment: What about TS version? Should I change it from 3.4.5 to something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193285/discussion-between-dota2pro-and-mark).

Comment: For `ts-enum-util` specifically, you'll have to upgrade to version 3+ when upgrading typescript to 2.9+. You should be getting a peer dependency warning from NPM about `ts-enum-util` when an incompatible TypeScript version is installed.

Typescript 2.9 has a breaking change in how `keyof` works, so I had to create a new major version of `ts-enum-util` to deal with it. See my release notes for each release for details about how you might have to change your code when upgrading: https://github.com/UselessPickles/ts-enum-util/releases

Answer (score 2):

I face the same error and the command shown below solve my problem. That is, It install the latest required version.

```
npm install typescript@">=3.1.1 and <3.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

update your Typescript to 3.1.6 in package.json

```
"typescript": "~3.1.6",
```

Comment: If I do that then I get many errors that look like this: ERROR in node_modules/ts-enum-util/dist/types/index.d.ts(23,101): error TS2344: Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
node_modules/ts-enum-util/dist/types/index.d.ts(76,57): error TS2344: Type 'keyof T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: yes, Typescript 3.1+ version has got strict type checking. you need to clean your node_modules, clean `npm` cache and reinstall `npm` dependencies.

Comment: I did this: npm cache clean --force and then npm install. did not help.

Comment: That means you need to update your `ts-enum-util` to be compatible with your typescript version. What version do you have for ts-enum-util?